# Помогите разобраться с InputStream в Socket

Tags: android, java

Выложил код по ссылке, гляньте плиз. http://pastebin.com/Sfb890W4

Я решил по 1024 байта, передавать. Я не понимаю почему так происходит...http://pastebin.com/Sfb890W4. При отладке все работает, а если при обычном режиме то бред какой. Вот по ссылке перейдите там все описал.

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: я тоже. какие данные в этом потоке, почему именно 1024, и почему такая логика с break?

Comment: Да в Асинк Таске. Результаты вывода воспроизводяться. И я слышу последнее слово. Ладно сейчас попробую Звуковой файл передать.
Кажись я понял в чем проблема была), щас еще протестью.

Отправил файл готовый, результат как в файле, байты ссответсвуют размеру. Но из цикла ен выходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ((request=inputStream.read(data))>0)

Как минимум из-за этой строчки цикл уже не бесконечный, при условии конечно что поток не бесконечный. а что за поток, откуда в нем данные берутся? полагаю, что он может не успевать заполняться например, отсюда разные результаты в отдалке и в run-режиме. ну то есть в поток(stream) приходят данные в потоке(thread), соотвественно в отладке есть паузы, когда stream успевает заполняться, а при исполнении нету. это первое что приходит в голову по поводу разных результатов.

Я про закрытие ничего не говорил. поток это такая труба. один в неё кладет данные с одной стороны, другой вытаскивает с другой. тот вывод, который у вас на pastebin подталкивает подозревать, что тот, кто кладет данные в поток просто не успевает их класть, в то время как другой их читает. socket заполняется в AsyncTask, и читается в нем же? результаты вывода в обычном режиме работы(не в отладке) всегда одинаковые?

вы же что-то писали по пунктам там.. зачем удалили?

> Почему в Java все так проблематично то?. Он делается все, милиярд поток создает и все...а то что файл еще не записался или не считалось кто за этим должен сдледать? Я что ли, если у этих классов даже нет таких методов блин!!!!!!

Не надо нервничать. я пытаюсь помочь, только вы огрызками даете информацию. поставьте себя на место отвечающего и посмотрите на вопрос. например, если кто-то другой войдет сейчас в вопрос, то он ничего не поймет, потому что в вопросе нет самого вопроса, есть только ссылка на кусок кода, хотя сперва кода больше было.

Comment: @iksuy, Помоги из цикла выйти а?. Не разрывая связи как можно ис цикла выйти...

Comment: Вот так всегда, закинут и фиг кто поможет, а уже почти заработало... Да и почему у меня -1 то опять...было же 40 очков..

Comment: я просто не до конца осознал всё происходящее в логике. если бы вы чётко сформулировали задачу.

Comment: я по-прежнему не понимаю связи между методом doInBackground и тем кодом, в котором у вас проблемы. я уже спрашивал, но однозначного ответа не получил, тот код, в котором проблемы написан внутри того же самого AsyncTask?

Comment: @iksuy, 
Вот мой гавнокод((
http://pastebin.com/naXmN6ay

@gcoder, Вы правы, в голове у меня каша, после всего этого...

Comment: ну вот, они работают в разных потоках, как я и говорил. вы вызываете старт потока в конструкторе MySocket. может логичнее было бы это делать в момент вызовы AsyncTask?